# How to Join two entity in hibernate if they have no association

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee

I have two entities which has no association between them. But I need to combine those two tables and transform to model . I create criteria with tutorial. I could not find how can i join those two tables and get name of the student name from the student table. History includes started course date and completed date . It should inject also course complete date if exists.

```
class Model {
  string studentName;
  string tutorialName;
  date courseCompletedDate;
}

class student {
  long studentId;
  string studentName;
}

class tutorial {
   long studentId;
   string tutorialName;
   date courseHour; 
   Set<History> history;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I edit the content. Tried native query and hql .The problem in native query , i could not select completed date from history .Because it maybe does not exist completed date in history. Hql problem is as i said in above , i could not select from the tutorial , i need something like createAlias Join with student .But i could not find the way.